# Have XCode add missing methods from "incomplete implementation" warnings

Tags: xcode4.6

Is it possible to have XCode 4.6.3 automatically add the methods listed as missing by the yellow "incomplete implementation" warning sign?

If not, is it possible to have XCode automatically complete a method signature from an adopted protocol as I type?

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to implement the method yourself.